# Onclick event only works on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

My `onclick` event only works on double click. I searched the previous similar questions also but none of them worked. Please if anyone can help me with this.

```
function getDetails(tablename,field)
{  
    goToFind("0"+tablename);
    var prntid=sessionStorage.getItem('prnt_id');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'addresses/getAddressDetails',
      type: "post",
      data: {'tablename':tablename,'fld':field,'prntid':prntid},
      success: function(data){
         var obj = JSON.parse(data);
       res=res.split("|");
       var str="<center><input type='button' value='Exit' onclick=javascript:window.close();opener.window.focus();></center><br/><table border=1>";
       str+="<tr>";
       for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++)
       {            
        str+="<th>"+res[i]+"</th>";            
       }
       str+="</tr>";

       for(j=0;j<obj.length;j++)
    {
         str+="<tr>";
       for(i=0;i<res.length;i++)
       {           
        str+="<td>"+obj[j][res[i]]+"</td>";            
       }
       str+="</tr>";
    }
    str+="</table>";

     z = window.open('', 'popUp','height=' + screen.height + ',width=' + screen.width + ',resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes');
    z.focus();
    z.document.open();
    z.document.write(str);
      }  
     });
}
```

Here I am calling my method from index page

```
<button class="w3-btn w3-brown" value='skip' onclick="getDetails('addresses','party_id')">Current Party Address</button>
```

Comment: Is your html comes from ajax?

Comment: That's why its not working from one click. You have to bind your jquery code on ajax load then you able to trigger it with on click.

Comment: @AjayMakwana: All event handlers shown are inline `onclick=`, so that does not explain why two clicks are needed.

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye : Yes you are right. But this was happend to me also and i found the solution on that way(Function also bind with ajax code) and its working great.